# Dynamic query parameters Retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit

Hello im giving the first steps inRetrofit, i want to change this URL dynamically   ||(DOMAIN).com/Program/v7/Programs/NowAndNextLiveChannelPrograms?UserAgent=AND&$filter=CallLetter%20eq%20%27**FOX**%27&$orderby=StartDate%20asc ||   So i can change the channel in this case is FOX.

this is my GET

```
   @GET("Program/v7/Programs/NowAndNextLiveChannelPrograms?UserAgent=AND&$filter=CallLetter%20eq%20%27SIC%27&$orderby=StartDate%20asc")
    Call<EPGResponse> getEPG(@Query("???")  ???  );
```

CALL

```
   DataService canaisDataService = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();

        Call<EPGResponse> call = canaisDataService.getEPG("PASS CHANNEL FORM LIST");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EPGResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EPGResponse> call, Response<EPGResponse> response) {
                 epgResponse = response.body();

                if (epgResponse !=null && epgResponse.getValue() != null){

                    epgValueList = epgResponse.getValue();
                    mutableLiveDataEPG.setValue(epgValueList);

                }
            }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the url (with the query) by String but you need to build before the call:

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET
    Call<EPGResponse> getEPG(@Url String url);
}
```

Comment: but s possibel to query only the channel?

Comment: Retrofit documentation:  * URL resolved against the {@linkplain Retrofit#baseUrl() base URL}.  Another option, depend of your case, it is to create another retrofit instance and inject it by constructor.  Each instance can have a different base url.

Answer (score 0):

First, the make your URL with your query parameter like this,

```
String url = "(DOMAIN).com/Program/v7/Programs/NowAndNextLiveChannelPrograms?UserAgent=AND&$filter=CallLetter%20eq%20%27SIC%27&$orderby=StartDate%20asc"
```

Then pass URL into APIService's getEPG() like this,

```
 DataService canaisDataService = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();

        Call<EPGResponse> call = canaisDataService.getEPG(url);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EPGResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EPGResponse> call, Response<EPGResponse> response) {
                 epgResponse = response.body();

                if (epgResponse !=null && epgResponse.getValue() != null){

                    epgValueList = epgResponse.getValue();
                    mutableLiveDataEPG.setValue(epgValueList);

                }
            }
```

Your APIService like this,

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET
    Call<EPGResponse> getEPG(@Url String url);
}
```

if you want pass Query Parameter you can also add @Query After @Url like this,

```
 public interface APIService {
        @GET
        Call<EPGResponse> getEPG(@Url String url,@Query("parameter") String parameter) ;
    }
```